# Use Icon in jcheckbox instead of text

Tags: java, swing, jcheckbox

I need to add an icon of an "envelope" to a jcheckbox. The documentation seems to focus on replacing the selected/unselected state icons.

I am happy with those - but I want an "envelope" picture rather than text saying "email".

Answer (score 2):

Create a JCheckbox without a label.  Then place it next to a JLabel using an icon.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();

    JCheckBox box = new JCheckBox();
    JLabel label = new JLabel(myIcon);

    panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
    panel.add(box);
    panel.add(label);

    frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: Yes, but I want to enable/disable sometimes. Nice if I only had to remember to do it to one item

Comment: @ManInMoon I suppose you could abstract it out and create your own widget (something like the above) incorporating both components.  Then override the `setEnabled()` method to apply it to both the label and checkbox.